# https lock and company name in address bar

Tags: url, ssl, ssl-certificate

I noticed when looking at paypal's website they have their company name next to the lock icon in chrome. Is this because they authored their ssl cert or how do you think they achieved this? It's something I've been curious about and I'm having trouble finding any answers during my searches.

[image: paypal-ssl]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a certificate which is called "Extended valiation" (EV) certificate.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate